# ¿Como evitar arrastrar una imagen en una Página web?

Tags: html, jquery, jsf, spring-mvc

Hola a todos como hago para evitar que el **ratón de la PC** al dar click en la `imagen` no pueda arrastrarse en la pagina web, no se si me explico bien pero dicha imagen que tengo tiene un atributo `src` que llama a un Servlet y si lo arrastro hacia un `campo de texto` pues entonces muestra la **URL** con el nombre del Servlet que lo llamó.
Quiero evitar eso como se puede hacer.
Cualquier código que solucione esto sería bueno.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Opción `CSS`

Solo con `CSS` puede usar [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```css
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
```

---

#### Opción `JS`

Suscribimos una función al evento `dragstart` del `document` en la cual detectamos si el elemento que se esta intentando arrastrar es una imagen y lo evitamos.

Con `JS` puro:

```js
// Event delegation
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName == 'IMG') {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
```

Con `jQuery`

```js
$(document).on('dragstart', 'img', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
```

**Nota**: El **pro** de utilizar estas técnicas, es que no tienes que agregar manualmente a todas las imágenes un atributo.

Comment: Espectacular amigo

Answer (score 3):

Puedes logar lo que quieres utilizando la propiedad HTML `draggable` asi:

```html
<img id="myImage" draggable="false" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
```